# Using Emacs client with multiple clients

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I recently started using emacsclient, and I like it a lot. Until now I haven't had any problems, but I just made a new tab in my terminal and tried opening another file, but emacs gets stuck on "Waiting for Emacs...". How do I run two emacsclients so I can edit two files? I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 with emacsclient 23.4 and emacs 23.4.1.

In order to start emacsclient and emacs server, I have the following bash function:

```
function emacs {
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        emacsclient -c -nw -a ""
    else
        emacsclient "$@" -a ""
    fi
}
```

So for example I could start a terminal and emacs server would not be running. Then I would type `emacs file.txt` which would start an emacs server and connect with an emacs client. Then I would make a new tab and type `emacs file2.txt` and I wouldn't be able to connect.